# Google Classroom - Student Comments API

Tags: google-workspace, google-classroom

I need to retrieve students comments in Google Classroom.  Is there an API that does this?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the day of this posted answer, there is no direct way of retrieving private comments from students in Google Classroom using [Google Classroom's API](https://developers.google.com/classroom).

However, this feature has been requested by several users, you can follow the progress of this feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36882823). Moreover, I do recommend you to **star this feature request** as that will raise its priority.