# (Python) Google Drive API: get mime type of file from id in a non-awkward way

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-classroom

I need to download Google Drive files that are attached to Google Classroom submissions.
From the Google Class "Submission" I get some information that does **not** include the mime type:

```
{
   "driveFile":{
       "id":"10NDXAyz8gkWzkXPS[removed]",
       "title":"git bash.PNG",
       "alternateLink":"https://drive.google.com/file/d/10NDXAyz8gkWzkX[removed]/view?usp=drive_web",
       "thumbnailUrl":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nf4i[removed]=s200"
   }
}
```

If I understand correctly the mime type is needed to know which one is the right method to invoke for download, ie.

```
service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType=export_mime_type
```

versus

```
service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id))
```

So far I have found only a very awkward way to get the mime type (code at the bottom).

This is to ask if there is, using the API, a less awkward way, I searched but cannot find it.
In my code splitting the ...thing in 2 functions is intentional, the awkwardness is in having to query by name, and them check the id.
I wonder if there is some more appropriate "method" than files.list() to invoke.
If there isn't whether it is possible to query by id with it. I did not find that in the doc, tried it anyway but it did not work

```
def get_file_from_id_name(file_id, file_name, gdrive_service):
    """it seems I can only query by name, not by id"""
    page_token = None
    while True:
        query = "name='{}'".format(file_name)
        response = gdrive_service.files().list(spaces='drive', q = query, 
            fields='nextPageToken, files({})'.format(ALL_FILE_FIELDS),
            pageToken=page_token).execute()

        for file in response.get('files', []):
            if file.get('id') == file_id:
                return file
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break

    log.info("breakpoint")
    return None

def get_mime_type_from_id_name(file_id, file_name, gdrive_service):
    file_d = get_file_from_id_name(file_id, file_name, gdrive_service)
    mime_type = file_d.get("mimeType")
    return mime_type
```

Sorry for the long detailed question, tried to make it as concise as possible

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that in Python you can use [`mimetypes.guess_type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html) to retrieve the mimetype of a file. You can check this [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/upload-and-download-files-from-google-drive-storage-using-python/) so you can have an idea. This is how it was done in that scenario:

```
mimetype = MimeTypes().guess_type(name)[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my question was about getting sure info from the API itself, i improved my question making that explicit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After some further unfruitful research it seems that there isn't a way to get the mime type *from the API*.
This inference is also supported by the fact that the API does not cover all the feature and data available, see for instance the current lack of API support for a very important feature like [private comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61007360/9715069) (currently approved but not yet available)